# Two Sum LeetCode - why my own code failed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem:

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target. You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

---

My code:

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    for x in nums:
        for y in nums: 
            if nums.index(x) != nums.index(y) and x + y == target :
                    return [nums.index(x), nums.index(y)]

 print (twoSum ([3, 3],6))
```

Output:

```
null
```

In my mind the first "iteration" (I am not quite sure if this is the right term) looks like :

```
If 0 != 0 (False) and 3 + 3= 6 (True)  --> as  the first condition is not met, the y loops
```

So the next iteration looks like:

```
If 0 != 1 (True) and 3 + 3 = 6 (True)
```

--> as above conditions are met, the function would return `[0,1]`, but instead the code actually returns `null` and I do not understand the reason.

So, I  would really appreciate, if someone could either explain what's happening, or  tell me some keywords, in order to search for the answer on my own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MoxieBall pointed out, your code returns `None` because `.index()` returns the index of the *first* matching value.

You can use `enumerate()` to get the true index location:

```
for x_index, x_value in enumerate(nums):
    for y_index, y_value in enumerate(nums):
        if x_index != y_index and x_value + y_value == target:
            return [x_index, y_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `index` method will find the index of the first occurrence in the list. Since your list has the same number twice, no call to `index` in your code as written will ever return anything except 0. Thus, `if nums.index(x) != nums.index(y)` is never `True` so your function returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I think since both the elements in [3,3] are same, hence nums.index(x) and nums.index(y) always give 0 which is equal hence the if-block never execute.

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
  for x in range(len(nums)):
    for y in range(len(nums)): 
        if x != y and nums[x] + nums[y] == target :
                return [x, y]
print (twoSum ([3, 3],6))
```

this is my solution.